# Is there a way to add a logo for sonata admin group?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have installed SonataMediaBundle and SonataUserBundle. 
When I go to my admin dashboard I see a logo visible in the sidebar for each group (user and media).
Then I have added an other group manually (event), but the logo displayed is just a folder image and it's the same for all the other groups manually added.

[image: My sidebar in sonata admin dashboard]

Do you know a way to customize the logo groups and replace folder image ? 
Cheers !

PS : the groups are displayed in French (Evenements -> Events; Utilisateurs -> Users; Mediathèque-> Media)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register your admin service you have additional options:

`on_top: true, icon: '<i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>'`

`on_top` - this will make your admin class on top and not in a folder/group

`icon` - this will change logo

you do it like this:

```
app.admin.youradmin:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\YourAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: YourAdmin, on_top: true, icon: '<i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>' }
```

Comment: @Putxe glad to help :)